# As our velocity changes shouldn't the span of time taken change

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

We all know the variation in the velocity of an individual causes different time periods . If we move with the speed of light ,then the time stops for us. Then why does sunlight take time to reach us?

Comment: You cannot apply that logic for both massive particles and light particles, they behave in a different fashion.

Comment: The comoving frame of a photon is not an inertial frame of reference and thus concepts from relativity are not equipped to describe what happens there. Indeed, it may not even make sense to think about a photon's point of view.